# Testing my programs in Windows XP environment

Tags: testing, windows-xp, virtual, virtualization, vmware

I wrote a few cool programs and tested them with Windows 7 and OS X and they work perfectly. But apparently some of my clients still use Windows XP. I dont have any XP boxes and I've heard that MS doesnt support it any more. Is there a way to somehow test it in Windows XP? Should I go to some used computer stores to buy computers with Windows XP? Is there a way to emulate running XP using one of those Virtual PC programs?

Comment: XP is still in extended support by MS http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-gb&C2=1173 until mid-2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Windows XP Mode, or use VirtualBox. Both free.

Comment: Or VMWare player or VirtualPC (to be thorough) - although XP mode is just a specialised instance of VirtualPC

Comment: I like XP Mode because it is supported by Microsoft. VMware products have huge memory footprints while VirtualBox is nearly infinitesimal in comparison.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check the XP Mode